# How to call a parent scope function in directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I want to call a Controller function in the directive template. 
This is not working:

Controller:

```
myApp.controller('StartController', ['$scope', '$location',  function ($scope, $location) {

    $scope.changeLocation = function (path) {
        $location.path(path);
    }
 }]);
```

the index.html:

```
<div start-directive changelocation="changeLocation">
</div>
```

the directive:

```
myApp.directive('startDirective', function ($templateRequest, $compile) {
    return {
        restrict: 'AE',
        transclude: true,
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            var baseSiteUrlPath = $("base").first().attr("href");
            $templateRequest(baseSiteUrlPath + '/App/Templates/uxStart.html').then(function (html){
                var template = angular.element(html);
                element.append(template);
                $compile(template);
            });

        }
    };
});
```

and the uxStart.html

```
<div class="box1 square1">
    <button class="indexBtn" ng-click="$parent.changeLocation('/index')">Fahrplan & Buchung</button>
</div>

<div class="box2 square2">
    <button class="serviceBtn" ng-click="changeLocation('/pageNotFound')">Services</button>
</div>
```

What I am doing wrong?

thx in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have not compiled your element with scope, you have only create the compile function of that template like `$compile(template)`, which wouldn't compile that element. You need to call compile function by passing scope parameter in it.

As your directive is using shareable scope, then you don't need to mention `$parent` before calling method.

**Directive**

```
myApp.directive('startDirective', function($templateRequest, $compile) {
  return {
    restrict: 'AE',
    transclude: true,
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      var baseSiteUrlPath = $("base").first().attr("href");
      $templateRequest(baseSiteUrlPath + '/App/Templates/uxStart.html').then(function(html) {
        var template = angular.element(html);
        element.append(template);
        var linkFn = $compile(template);
        //compile it with scope to generated compiled DOM with scope
        linkFn(scope); //linking scope with template
      });

    }
  };
});
```

Comment: thanks. I also had to add the scope:{} in the directive. Then it worked.

Comment: @MinasMinas if you going to add `scope:{} ` in your directive..then you should pass that method inside that directive isolated scope..using `$parent` in that case going to mess..

Comment: @MinasMinas I'd say that..could you reproduce the problem with plunkr..then I could help you in that..

Comment: Yes, you was right. Actually i had $parent in front of the method. I removed the scope and the parent, and now it´s working

Comment: @MinasMinas Cool then..Glad to hear that..it worked..Thanks :)